# Difference between wine-wingdings and wingdings?

Tags: linux, windows, fonts, wine

Is there any difference between wine-wingdings and wingdings (the true-type font available with Microsoft Windows)?

By difference, I just mean is there any symbol that could be represented by wingdings (the true-type font available with Microsoft Windows) could not be represented by wine-wingdings.

Answer (score 2):

Wingdings is coming from the msttcorefonts package. Around at 2000 has the microsoft made its core fonts package free downloadable *"in the interests of the cross platform compatibility"*. Later they changed their view, and it was made closed again, but the at this time opened font files are still being widely used. These fonts don't change so fast (f.e. the times font is more than 100 years old), as the other software components of the world.

What in your situation important is: wine is running (probably) on a linux, and thus it uses the wingdings from the msttcorefonts package, which is the wingdings font, which was released by the microsoft around before 10-15 years.

It is very improbable, that the microsoft changed anything in this font (encoding changes don't count, the truetype font format uses unicode), but if it happened, it were some difference between them.

If you have a legal copy of a current windows OS, you are probably allowed to copy its wingdings font to your wine (search for a `wingdings.ttf` or some like so).

I didn't closed out minor differences between the wingdings fonts of the wine and the windows, mainly because the extensions/new pictures were of course impossible to get to the wine wingdings font.

But if you want to really see clear, get the free linux font editor named fontforge from [here](http://fontforge.org). Open both of the wingdings.ttf files, and if they differ, you will know this.

Comment: Ok, I've a wine-wingdings ttf file which is based upon EL6. After I installed it on Windows, I'm seeing that most of the text are not rendered in the wine-wingdings font itself. I see the symbols of wine-wingdings using Ms word - insert symbol, selecting font - wine-wingdings and seeing symbols. Is all the symbols of windings are mapped to wine-wingdings? Do I have a correct wine-wingdings ttf file, in which most of the characters are scrambled? Do the wine-wingdings-fonts maps only to some characters of wingdings?

Comment: @Prakhar What is EL6? I can't understand most of your comment. But anyways: there is a free trutetype font editor, its name is fontforge. Open both of the wingdings fonts, both from the wine and from your local windows installation, and compare them. I extended my answer with this.

Comment: By EL6 I mean, enterprise linux 6. I'm sorry I should be clear. The crux of my question is, does all the symbols of wine-wingdings are mapped to windows wingdings?

Comment: @Prakhar Get fontforge (maybe it is even in EL6, or at least there is an rpm existing), and look this.

Comment: Sure I'll get fontforge, but the wine-wingdings file I have is not having all the symbols in it and mostly symbols are represented as vertical rectangle.

Comment: @Prakhar There could be a lot of any cause of this problem, which is out of the scope of this question. You got the answer, now if you have further problems/questions you had to ask it as a new question and not getting this discussion to an infinite, unpaid support loop.

Comment: I'm sorry for it but the answer was not saying about whether all the symbols in wingdings are mapped with wine-wingdings-fonts symbols, which was my actual question, i guess. Anyways thanks for your "unpaid" support. :)

Comment: Exactly this is what I answered - you can compare the two ttf files with the fontforge tool. The few hindi I knew were all smart, diligent and honest, please don't disappoint me.

Comment: ;-) Indeed you are suggesting the way to look the TTF's and I appreciate the answer. Please don't get disappointed. It is really helpful. And we are not all Hindi here in India. :)

Comment: Note that the msttcorefonts package installs Webdings, not Wingdings. The two fonts have different character mappings.